# QGIS: GRASS GIS plugin not accepting UTM point coordinates

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-grass-plugin

I am using QGIS 3.16 with the GRASS plugin.

I imported a UTM point cloud (x,y,z) and successfully generated a TIN surface based on it (using QGIS own functionality).

But when I want to use GRASS `v.surf.rst` (using the same input points layer) I get the error:

```
C:\Users\mk\Documents>g.region n=2132823.133 s=2132590.681 e=439329.924 w=439144.2887 res=100.0
ERROR: Illegal latitude for North: 2.13282e+006
...
WARNING: Some points outside of region (ignored)
WARNING: There are points outside specified 2D/3D region - 663 points ignored
WARNING: Zero points in the given region
ERROR: Input failed
```

Apparently GRASS has a problem with the coordinate system (UTM).

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_FAQ#Errors  -- Grass is using a lat/lon coordinate system, so you first need to set up a non-lat/lon location for Grass to work in.  Try `Plugins/Grass/New Mapset/.../Create new Location/Projection/...` to make a new location for GRASS to work in.

[image] [image]